# read encryption attachment of .msg file in java

Tags: java, apache-poi, msg

I have many .msg files which has encrypted attachment. I currently use apache poi library. Currently, I  have code that giving a path of a .docx, .xls, .xlsx file, I can have the decrypted content. The problem is I want to get the attachment of msg file decrypted.

```
public static void decryptMSG(String path,String[] password) throws IOException {
    MAPIMessage msg = new MAPIMessage(path);
    AttachmentChunks attachments[] = msg.getAttachmentFiles();
    if(attachments.length > 0) {
        for (AttachmentChunks a  : attachments) {
            String attachname=a.attachLongFileName.toString();
            ByteArrayInputStream fileIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(a.attachData.getValue());
            File f = new File(path+"_decrypted"+ a.attachLongFileName.toString()); // output
            OutputStream fileOut = null;
            try {
                fileOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int bNum = fileIn.read(buffer);
                while(bNum > 0) {
                    fileOut.write(buffer);
                    bNum = fileIn.read(buffer);
                }   
            }
            finally{
                   .....
            }
```

This is the normal code to read .msg attachments which are not encrypted.

Q1: could sb kindly tell me where I can set the password?

Q2: if it's not  support by the library to set the password, is it possible to copy  the AttachmentChunks to a path? I mean give each Attachmentchunk a physical path where the Attachemntchunk is stored?

Q3: or if you know any lib in java or python could solve decrypting .msg file, please tell me. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `EncryptionKey`/`EncryptionInfo` (depending on the encryption method). See [this page](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html) for a more in-depth explanation.